# Bamboo: maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, maven-3, pom.xml, bamboo

I am trying to build a sample Java image using bamboo via a Dockerfile. But I'm getting this error. We have added the proxy settings in `settings.xml` in `~/.m2` folder.

I have referred to similar questions, and most of the solutions don't suit my situation.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  22.53kB
Step 1/8 : FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN
---> 293423a981a7
Step 2/8 : COPY pom.xml /tmp/
---> Using cache
---> b77d358f80b0
Step 3/8 : COPY src /tmp/src/
---> Using cache
---> d448db75d074
Step 4/8 : WORKDIR /tmp/
---> Using cache
---> 7c7a16ec65ab
Step 5/8 : RUN mvn package
---> Running in cc37fcc7488d
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.453 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-13T11:02:11Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Try again: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Try again -> [Help 1]
Removing intermediate container cc37fcc7488d
The command '/bin/sh -c mvn package' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failing task since return code of [/usr/bin/docker build --force-rm=true --tag=ackris/java-sample /app/bamboosoftware-home/xml-data/build-dir/CIB-CID-JOB1] was 1 while expected 0
```

It looks like a clear proxy related issue. As aforementioned, we have already appended proxy related information in `~/.m2` folder. Is there something needs to be done on bamboo level which I am forgetting?

**PS**: I am testing this out inside a corporate network, and we are behind a proxy. I am getting a value of 200 OK when I tried to telnet central Maven repo.

Comment: It looks like your docker image does not allow to go outside: ` Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Try again ->...` which the message states or something else is wrong.....Furthermore I would suggest to use volume mounts in your docker image instead of copying pom/src into the container....etc.

Comment: That’s not the issue. It is related with our organization’s security policies.

Comment: @khmarbaise have you got any other suggestion on how to overcome?

Comment: I would guess that Docker might have some proxy settings that would be worth looking into.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer sure mate...our docker set up is working without a hitch. All the proxy settings are enabled properly. It is doing good. As i said in my previous comment, the issue wrests with our organization’s security rules. Now i am really confused on how to use maven over here

Comment: You may be right, but I am not convinced. Indeed, perhaps it can be fixed at either point. The problem is that Maven is trying to make a curl request to an external host, and it is doing that inside Docker. I therefore wonder whether [configuring the proxy settings in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) would help.